# Continue executing a stopped process with SIGALRM in C

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, signals

the job is to continue executing a child process I stopped when I receive a SIGALRM signal.
so far I did the following, which doesn't seems to work:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void handler(int sig)
{
    printf("hello from the handler\n");
    kill(getpid(),SIGCONT);
     printf("child is continuing executing");
}

int main()
{
    int pid1=fork();
    signal(SIGALRM,handler);
    if (pid1==0) {
        kill(getpid(),SIGTSTP);
        printf(" I am in the child\n");
    } else {
        printf("i am in the parent \n");
        kill(pid1,SIGALRM);
    }
}
```

I've tried many variations of the code, but `printf("I am in the child");` is never executed.

Comment: OT: you should indent your code

Comment: And you can't safely call `printf()` from within a signal handler.

Comment: You confuse between the `pid`s. When your parent executes and calls `kill(pid1, SIGALRM)`, the signal handler is called and sends `SIGCONT` to the process who called it, which is the **parent**. You didn't post your exact output, but I guess that you did see the printing of the parent and the signal handler. Am I right?

Comment: The child process cannot run the SIGALRM handler while it is in the stopped state.

Comment: SpiderPig1297 yes and i also want in the output "I am in the child"
so how can I make the kill(pid1,SIGALRM) send the signal to the child

Answer (score 0):

Re: the question asked in a comment is ("how can I make the kill(pid1,SIGALRM) send the signal to the child?").  The call `kill(pid1,SIGALRM)` *does* send the signal to the child, but the child does not respond to it because it is stopped.  The question asked is somewhat ambiguous, as it is not clear who "I" refers to in the phrase "when I receive a SIGALRM signal".  If you want to have the child continue when the child receives a SIGALRM, you can't.  You must send the child a SIGCONT before it will do anything.  If you want the child to continue when the  parent receives the SIGALRM, you could so something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

pid_t pid1;
void handler(int sig)
{
        (void)sig;
        if( pid1 ) {
                kill(pid1, SIGCONT);
        }
}

int main(void)
{
        signal(SIGALRM, handler);
        pid1 = fork();
        if( pid1 == 0 ) {
                kill(getpid(), SIGTSTP);
                printf("Child continued\n");
        } else {
                alarm(1);
                pause();
        }
}
```